# PrintWindow() returns black image

Tags: c#, flash, winapi, firefox, graphics

I have written a program in C# for automation. It runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 and captures screenshots of a flash app, that runs inside Firefox. These images are then analysed to read the status of the flash app.

When the connection to the server is establish through "Remote Desktop Connection" and I can see the desktop of the server, then PrintWindow() usually works (it returns black images randomly, but I can live with that). But when I disconnect the Remote Desktop, and stop seeing the desktop, PrintWindow() fails and returns only black images.

I can't keep open connection to the server forever, can this behaviour be fixed?

Comment: When connected in remote desktop, do you get blank images only when the remote desktop window is minimized?

Comment: Can you check if this link is helpful? http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/134261-user32dll-printwindow-in-a-disconnected-remote-desktop-session/

Comment: Can you check if this registry settings is helpful? http://smartestudio.com/wiki/index.php?title=Execute_Under_VM_or_Remote_Desktop

Comment: Unfortunately these solutions didn't help me directly, the first one would have worked if I had Windows Server 2003 and not 2008. But when digging dipper into the links you gave me I found a solution: UltraVnc - it lets me log in to console session and even if connection is closed, the GFX still functions the normal way. Thank you!